# text-transform: lowercase is not working in email templates

Tags: html, css, email, sharepoint

I using sharepoint list having email template and using variables to get values.
Here is the sample code:

```
A new <span style="text-transform: lowercase;">$RequestType$</span> request has been submitted.
```

RequestType - StackOverflow

**When I am receiving email in outlook I want text as:**

*A new stackoverflow request has been submitted.*

**But its coming as:**

*A new StackOverflow request has been submitted.*

I don't see any issues in the code, need some suggestions.

Comment: You should add the complete source code of the received email, copied from raw email text data.

Comment: try this resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.tolower(v=vs.110).aspx You can run your variable thru lowercase and then display inside the email. It might work that way.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently MS Outlook only partially supports text-transform: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/text-fonts/text-transform/

Only uppercase is supported.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Email client support is essential since workarounds may differ from one client to the next.

Answer (score -1):

Your letters remain uppercase inside span, they are just displayed as lowercase, maybe that's why it doesn't work well... see what I mean: [image]

Instead use PHP:

```
strtolower("Hello WORLD.");
```

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp

or JavaScript:

```
str.toLowerCase();
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp

This looks good: 
[image: image2]

Comment: This is .net application. I can't switch on php just for this

Comment: then find a solution for .net, I can't help you with .net, but you should be able to find a solution now when you know what's wrong with your code. Good luck

Comment: If you can use JavaScript try str.toLowerCase();https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp